# How do I solve Error in n %*% s : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r

How do I resolve the error Error in n %*% s : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

```
library(foreign)
library(discSurv)
library(mgcv)
library(gamlss.mx)
library(mgcv)
library(MASS)
library(nlme)
library(glmmLasso)



attach(dataset)
AFI <- NULL
CNS <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(AFA)) {
  AFI[i] <- ifelse(is.na(AFA[i]) == TRUE, Age[i], AFA[i])
  CNS[i] <- ifelse(is.na(AFA[i]) == TRUE, 0, 1)
  
}
dataset <- data.frame(cbind(dataset, AFI, CNS))
dtLong <-
  as.data.frame(dataLong (
    dataSet = dataset,
    timeColumn = "AFI",
    censColumn = "CNS"
  ))



glm1 <-
  glmmLasso(
    y ~ as.factor(timeInt) + as.factor(Sex) + as.factor(MaritalS) ,
    family = binomial(link = logit),
    data = dtLong,
    lambda = 5,
    switch.NR = T,
    final.re = TRUE
  )
```

The data is given on

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o4kgsXvmsZrEkqvZAo3o0dgLBOB58YN5

Comment: The datafile on google drive is not readeable.

Comment: Why  `as.factor ` in the glmmLasso call  ? Should it no be numbers rather than factors ?

Comment: I think the data is now accessible